# How to change references to show Art. no. instead of no

Tags: ieeetran, ieeeaccess

I'm using a template from IEEE Access that uses the bibliography style IEEEtranN but I can't manage to change the bibliography style to show `Art. no.` instead of `no.` as the journal requests.

Any idea how can I change this? Thank you very much in advance.

Edit: ideally I would like the solution to also work in overleaf but I can’t manage to access .bst files in overleaf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have misinterpreted the IEEE guidelines. They intend to use the string "Art. no." in lieu of "pp." when an article has a specific number, rather than a page range. This is becoming more common as articles are published exclusively online.

This can be clearly seen in the examples given in the [IEEE Reference Guide](https://ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/wp-content/uploads/IEEE-Reference-Guide.pdf):

[image: image from IEEE Reference Guide]

As you can see, these example references have a volume and issue number (the correct use of the `bibtex` `number` field) and an additional article number that appears at the end.

The `IEEEtranN` doesn't have a field for article number, so the best way to do this is to use the `note` field, which will be printed as the last element of the reference. Since the `.bst` file lowercases everything by default, I've protected the capitalization of the `Art.` with braces. Ideally the `.bst` file should be updated to incorporate this as a proper field, but for the moment this suffices.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}


@article{FardelNagelNuesch2007,
    author = {Fardel, R. and Nagel,  M. and Nuesch, F. and Lippert, T.  and Wokaun, A.},
    journal = {Appl. Phys. Lett.},
    month = {Aug},
    note = {{A}rt. no. 061103},
    number = {6},
    title = {Fabrication of organic light emitting diode pixels by laser-assisted forward transfer},
    volume = {91},
    year = {2007}}

\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranN}

\begin{document}
\cite{FardelNagelNuesch2007}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thanks, I will try that out. Do you know if this solution works in overleaf? I can’t access .bst files in overleaf, I just see the .cls files from ieee. In texShop I managed to extract the bibitems from the bbl file created upon compilation and edit myself each entry with a regex in order to add `Art.`.

Comment: @CarlosVega You can always download a copy from CTAN: https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/bibtex

Comment: @CarlosVega It also occurs to me that this requirement is non-sensical: the number in an article entry is the issue number of the volume, not the article number. Are you sure you've interpreted their requirement correctly?

Comment: They were quite clear about it `Remember page number ranges are indicated with "pp." but for article number use "Art. no."`.

Comment: I tested your solution. It worked great, also in Overleaf by including the modified .bst file on the same folder. Thanks!

Comment: @CarlosVega I've deleted my previous answer and replaced it with one that follows the IEEE guidelines as written. :)

Comment: Thanks. Sometimes they have both pp. and Art. no. I understand they want to have Art. no. whenever there is an article number on the bibliography item. But perhaps is true that sometimes the bibtex uses number for article and others for issue number… I will check!

Comment: @CarlosVega The `number` field should simply never be used for article numbers. It will always end up in the wrong place in the reference formatting since all bibliography styles will use it to mean issue number of a volume. So stick to using `note` even if there is a page range.

Comment: I will check but I'm not bulding myself the bibtext entries. I'm taking them from automatic places such as Google Scholar, Mendeley, or the article websites. I hope they are correct but I will check. Thanks for the insight and help!